# How to test and improve my volume for the other side with Google Talk?

Tags: google-talk

I often make phone calls with Google Talk (i.e. the phone icon from Gmail) where I can hear the other side well but they have a hard time hearing me unless I speak very loudly near my laptop's microphone. I don't know if this is something wrong with my microphone, Gmail settings, or Internet upload speed.

How do I determine what the problem is and improve it?

Comment: The best thing you can do is use a headset. Do you have mic problems with other apps?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is find the mic software settings on your machine and, if it allows you to, increase the mic gain.